# excel losing connection to vba module

Tags: excel, vba

For the second time on 2 separate workbooks, excel appears to have lost its connection to the VBA module.

When looking for the macro names, normally it would show as eg: "Test_Macro".

In these instances, it then shows as "Myworkbook.xlsm.module1!.Test_Macro".

To rectify this, Ive had to open a new session of excel, turn off macros in trust centre. Go back to the file that has an issue, change the name of the macro (none of the code), and save. Turn macros back on. Go back to the failing file, rename back to what it was before, and it works again.

So whilst the fix is easy, im trying to find the route cause. Has anyone had this happen before, and if so, can they shed some light on this?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is that an issue? It would usually just mean that the macro is not in the activeworkbook, or you have two Test_Macro macros available.

Comment: Hi Rory, sorry perhaps i hadnt worded that right. So the activeworkbook had been running fine for a long time, then seemingly randomly it would error saying the module cannot be found. By doing the above steps, it then worked again. Only 1 workbook, with 1 "Test_Macro".

Comment: I've never heard of that. What exactly are you doing when the error happens?

Comment: nothing out of the ordinary! The macros arent exactly complicated either. The just auto run on open, refresh some data connections and update some formulas. Unfortunately now ive resolved it i cant get the exact error message. If i can ill keep this thread open and if/when it happens again ill take screenshots

Comment: **How** do they auto run on open?

Comment: name the macro auto_open

Comment: sub auto_open() *some code* end sub

Comment: So what's the actual error? I can't see that you would get anything like you described in your original post - unless you are using `Run` for some reason?